# .Net MVC integration with Azure Ad B2C signuponly and password reset custom policy returns id_token as # fragment in the url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to integrate .net MVC application with Azure B2C.

Azure B2C has been setup with custom policy for Signup and ResetPassword flow.

After signup and password reset, I am unable to get the token on the server side. Token is been sent over the url as the fragment #id_token. 
Do I need to specify anything in the custom policy to change the token from fragment to query or form_post?

Tried to add Metatag in the RelyingParty PasswordReset file.

```
 <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />      
      <InputTokenFormat>JWT</InputTokenFormat>
            <Metatag>
            <Item Key="response_types">id_token</Item>
            <Item Key="response_mode">query</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">email openid</Item>
            </Metatag>
```

But the xsd failed to parse the file with the following error :

The element 'TechnicalProfile' in namespace
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06' has invalid child element 'Metadata' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06'
. Looks like tag cannot be added directly to the relying party file

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions

Answer (score 0):

To Change the fragment #id_token you need to set "response_mode" parameter value as "query" or "form_post"(default).

After the user completes the user flow, a response is returned to your application at the indicated redirect_uri parameter, by using the method that's specified in the response_mode parameter. The response is the same for each of the preceding cases, independent of the user flow.

For more information please refer [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect#send-authentication-requests).

If you would like to request an access token go through the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens#request-a-token).

Make sure you are using the right elements in the relyingparty. There is Metadata element in the RelyingParty not the metatag.

Please refer the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/relyingparty)

Comment: Thanks I was able to get the token on the server side using form_post. However there is no logon session in the .net application after user goes through signup process. I was hoping the Owin UseCookieAuthentication will create the login session. I can see there is a valid Id_token, but no session cookie.

Comment: Please raise new Stack overflow Question as this is new query